# Enumerate all Vista/7 audio "sessions", as displayed in the Volume Mixer

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

In windows Vista & 7*, how would you enumerate the programs which are currently playing audio (or trying to, in the event master volume is muted)?  Essentially, I need the data displayed in the Volume Mixer found in the notification area.

Master volume is pretty easy:
ISimpleAudioVolume::GetMasterVolume()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679156(VS.85).aspx

But nothing about particular programs is forthcoming.

*Obviously the target is Vista, but I see no reason a solution wouldn't also work in 7.

Language is irrelevant, though C# would be appreciated.

Comment: Should we be assuming the language is C++?

Comment: Are you planning on using C++ or .NET?

Comment: C++, C#, whatever.  I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately your answer is incorrect.  Check out the [IAudioSessionManager2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370950(VS.85).aspx) interface - the RegisterSessionNotification API is your friend.

Comment: Looks like a handy interface! However the MSDN documentation for it says it requires Windows 7 - is this true, and if so is there any equivalent for Vista?

Comment: Unfortunately the API is a new addition to Windows 7.